# Number of $3$-letter words than can be formed from 'ABCDEA'?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I think I have a vague idea of what needs to be done, but I am stuck.

There are $5$ given letters, with $1$ letter repeated twice.

So to select $3$-letter words, we can select either $3$  letters out of $5$, or select $1$ letter out of $4$ with the repeated letter appearing twice.

$3$ distinct letters out of $5$ can be selected with $P(5,3) = 5!/2! = 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 60$.

How do I proceed from here? Or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: What you have done thus far is correct.  As for words with a repeated letter, choose the other letter and its location.  That completely determines the word.

Comment: So you should be getting $P(5,3) + 4\cdot 3 = 72$ as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A show up once the are $^5 P_3$ possibilities (you need to arranje three letters from a pool of five: A, B, C, D, E with no repeated letters;

If A show up twice u have 4*3 combinations (1 of 4 letters and 3 possible places);

Just add the result of each of the three cases.

Comment: You're including possibilities where A doesn't show up in the 2nd case. The first case is unnecessary.

Comment: You are absolutely right! The answer is just $^5 P_3$ + 4*3 then, thank you